# relational algebra for Limit Operator

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

What is relational algebra for these two SQL queries:

```
Select * from film where film_rating = 'PG' limit 20;
```

How can we show limit?

```
Select * from actor, country where first_name='BOB' and country='In';
```

where first_name is actor's column and country is country table's column...there is no relationship between these two tables...they are independent tables...

so can we use join operator here?

Comment: Don't you have a 3rd table with relations to your 2 tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About the `limit` in relational algebra. Traditional relational algebra does not support anything like the `limit` in SQL. This problem has been recognized and studied by Li, Chang, Ilyas and Song in *RankSQL: query algebra and optimization for relational top-k queries* (SIGMOD 2005). They have proposed a monotonic scoring function *F* that ranks the results by the sorting operator *tauF*.

Comment: 1) 
Actually I know about this operator but problem is how to combine select,project and tauF

Π film_id, title, rating (σ rating= ‘PG’ (film))

This is for select part then how can we combine it with tauF?

2)
Also, tauF is for sorting so does LIMIT operation inbuilt performs sorting operation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm only answering the question about joining here.

There is a m : n relation between actors and film. It must be realized through an intermediate table, say `film_actors`. Also the country table probably has a short name like "In" and a long name like "India".

```
SELECT film.title, film_actors.role_type, actor.name, country.long_name
FROM
    film
    LEFT JOIN film_actors ON film.film_id = film_actors.film_id
    LEFT JOIN actor ON film_actors.actor_id = actor.actor_id
    LEFT JOIN country ON actor.country = country.short_name
```

If the country table has only one column with this short name, then it makes no sense to include it into your query at all. Do it only if country has some additional information that you want to include.

I used LEFT OUTER JOINS here. They are only requested, if the table on the right side may not always have related records. A cartoon probably has no actors. Otherwise use `INNER JOIN`