# How to express limit operator in relational algebra or extended relational algebra

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I have a SQL query as following:

```
select uname, city from USER
where uid = 
(
select bidder from BID
group by bidder
order by count(*) desc limit 1);
```

The SQL query is to find the user's username and city who has made the most bids. But I don't know how to express the limit operator in relational/extend relational algebra.

Thanks!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: There is typicallly no LIMIT in relational algebra. But you don't need it for this query. But there are lots of "relational algebras" so please give a reference to the one you are supposed to use.

Comment: If you limit 1 after order by a column descending then you are asking for the maximum value in the column. The row with a maximum value can be expressed using basic operators--no order by or limit needed. [tag:greatest-n-per-group] But COUNT per GROUP requires aggregate operators beyond the basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in Navathe's book and couldn't find any limit operator in relational algebra. This made me think that there's no limit operator in classical relational algebra. After a research, [Alexander Serebrenik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277111/alexander-serebrenik) confirm that in "[relational algebra for Limit Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229535/relational-algebra-for-limit-operator)" question!