# How to select a specific number of tuples in relational algebra?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

For example, suppose I have a relation `A(name, duration, rating)` with thousands of tuples, is it possible to select something like the 10 tuples with *highest* `rating` ?

The output would be a relation with 10 tuples, those with highest `rating` and any other wanted attribute. No need to be sorted.

Important: this is WITHOUT specifying a condition like `rating > 3`.

Comment: please post sample data and output

Comment: What dbms are you using? and give us the table structures

Comment: Im not using any dbms, I'm looking for a relational algebra query (or to know if it is possible to select a specific number of tuples using relational algebra)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [relational algebra for Limit Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229535/relational-algebra-for-limit-operator)

Comment: Please give a reference to which relational algebra you are using.